# Suggest a Corel Painter tag

Tags: support, status-completed, retag-request, tags

I´m learning Corel Painter. Very nice software, but a little overwhelming for new users,  I have a few questions, but Super User doesn´t have the proper tag, it has only CorelDraw, wich is no useful.

BTW: I want to retag this question: [Why does my Corel Painter eraser erase only squares?](https://superuser.com/questions/208825/why-my-corel-painter-eraser-erase-only-squares)

Answer (score 3):

The question is now tagged as [corel-painter](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/corel-painter) [image-manipulation](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/image-manipulation)

Comment: @Edgar You're welcome.